# Conflict Variable Value in Get/POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, actionresult

I have created a asp.net mvc application which has Get and Post method like

```
public ActionResult MyData(string companyid) 
{
    MyModel model= new MyModel (); 
    model = (LINQ) ;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyData(MyModel model) 
{
    if(model.companyid>0)
    { 
       //Update Database
    }
    else
    {
       // insert database
    }
    return View(model);
}


public class MyModel
{
   public int companyid {set; get;}
   public string Name {set; get;}
   public string Address {set; get;}
}
```

Now my question is: I am getting model.companyid =0 always in post i.e. @  if(model.companyid>0)

when I update the get method 
from public ActionResult MyData(string companyid) 
to public ActionResult MyData(string cid) 
it works.

i.e. rename companyid to cid, why it happens. Please let me know...I think, we have seperate method for get and post.

Comment: you probably have either a route with a parameter `{cid}` or the parameter is provided in the query string as in `foo.com/MyData?cid=123`

Comment: Did you somehow store the Company ID in your form view, e.g. in a hidden field? This is necessary if you need the Company ID in the controller.

Comment: Try to add virtual for the model fields.

Comment: I already have hidden field in view...